# How to build SEO URLs for e-commerce store with multiple categories?

Tags: url, seo

I want to ask how to SEO-wise properly structure URLs for e-commerce store (eshop) with multiple categories being nested in different ways.

Let's use example of cars. Customer can filter products using several features, by brand, car and fuel. And I want to use selected filter options in URL like this:

```
www.foo.com/mercedes
www.foo.com/blue-cars
www.foo.com/diesel-cars/blue-cars/mercedes
```

But I also want to maintain the navigation path user used to get to his filtered products. So the problem is, that I will have different URLs having exactly same content, e.g.:

```
www.foo.com/diesel-cars/blue-cars/mercedes
www.foo.com/mercedes/diesel-cars/blue-cars
www.foo.com/blue-cars/mercedes/diesel-cars
```

And so I will have duplicate content as well. I could/should do a rel="canonical" in those pages to one MAIN url, however, it stil will be a little mess. Any suggestion or best practice how to deal with this problem ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for SEO advice. (It might be on-topic on [webmasters.se].)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the same item (car) on multiple categories very often, you definitely risk a duplicate content issue.

Solutions:

- Have a main category only, ex: http://example.com/cars and add a query string for filtering ex: http://example.com/cars?color=blue

  Stackoverflow use a similar approach [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=featured):

  - Use canonical link to improve link and ranking signals for content available through multiple URL. More info from Google here:
    https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en